# Can you join a Minecraft public server from different devices on the same account?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I want to join a public Minecraft server on my laptop, but later on I will also want to join that same public server on another computer, with my data saved, using the same Minecraft account.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/606524-minecraft/69905804) explains the topic fairly well.

In short, as long as you are using the same account, your progress would not be lost.

When you log onto a server, a character file with your username is made and saved onto that specific server. When you log off, you won't lose anything (unless there's a server crash or something crazy) and when you log on to the server again, your items will still be there waiting for you.

Having that said, changing your playername would not cause progress loss on multiplayer. In addition, within a short period of time after you have your name changed, everyone on the server would see your previous name so that they can recognize you, which is a warm feature.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, so same account, different computer, i can still log in to the public server and pick up where I left off?

Comment: Affirmative. Yes

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add to hfanatic´s awnser, yes you can play with the same mojang account on different computers, but not at the same time. Otherwise you will lose your connection on one device. Because minecraft servers can't handle two computers with the same account at the same time.